# passing multiple dataframes to function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am new to python and pandas, am trying something as part of learning the langauge. I want to pass multiple columns of two different dataframe of same index into function and store the result in a third dataframe which has the same index as the first two. I used df.apply, however this will let me to pass only two columns of same dataframe. At this point i dont want to merge/join/concant columns into one single dataframe before passing int to the function. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

```
def R1(df):
    if df['OPEN']>df['CLOSE']:
        return "BEARISH"
    elif df['OPEN']<df['CLOSE']:
        return "BEARISH"
    
    
day1['type analysis'] = df.apply(R1,axis=1)
```

in the above mock code, the columns are from same dataframes, however i need to pass two columns ['OPEN'] & ['CLOSE'] from tow different dataframes df1 & df2 respcetivley. is there way to do so

Comment: your function can take as many input arguments as you want

Comment: you also don't need to `apply` that function

Comment: How do I pass df1['OPEN'] & df2['CLOSE'] to the function. I don't want to pass the whole dataframes either, just selected columns from it. But the results needs to be in third dataframe. Any sample snippet corde for that. The function here is simple one as it is mock code however there will be more calcialtions involved in it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Have you consulted the Pandas documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could define a function to concatenate the data frames.  As noted above, the data frames have same Index (row labels).

```
def f(*dfs):
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# call the function like this:
my_result = f(df1['col1'], df2['col2'], df3['col3'])
```